# Html and css with images overlaps in iText7 html to pdf conversion in java

Tags: java, itext7, html-to-pdf

I am adding images to my html file and trying to convert it to pdf. Though my html file shows images and css styles properly, pdf overlaps the content and doesn't show complete html file.

```
File dest = new File(\\some path\\ gen.pdf);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);

//pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.B0);
// I have tried PageSize and addPage but that didn't work maybe because I have added writer in PdfDocument and then added pages. I didn't find any other way of adding it (this also didn't work).
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.setBaseUri(absolutePath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(newHtmlFile); // passing here html file

HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(fis, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
```

**html**

in styles I have given `@page {  size: 11in 14in; }` also positions are `position:absolute;`

After converting to pdf I get the error:

> **c.i.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer     : Occupied area has not been initialized. Absolute positioning might be applied incorrectly.**

This is screenshot of html:

[image: html screenshot]

pdf created using itext7:
[image]

Thanks in advance I have tried everything but it didn't work for me I have also tried flying saucer in that also images are not loading. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please try to minimize the sample so that you can share it without and privacy concerns and it's possible to reproduce your problem

Comment: @AlexeySubach here is the html code [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CJYzXpdJ0iQPyk4k8l1c3rtkFVfeN7hFwSObRQa4N5c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is a bug in pdfHTML. You are using a lot of `position: absolute` declarations, so you may want to try to rewrite your HTML to contain more static layout instead of absolute

Comment: I can't have static layout. Sometimes there will be only one image and sometimes it could be upto five and I don't want to give fixed position because then empty page will not look good.

Comment: is there any solution to the issue? Please post.

Comment: No, I couldn't find any solution for it. Some dev said issue comes only in windows machine. I have used https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf for my development.